Overlay area not Cropping when crop function is clicked on it getting error in console
When i click on crop function getting and error message - Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The image argument is a canvas element with a width or height of 0.
Tried many ways got stuck here need to get the cropped image in base64 url.
I am building a standalone JavaScript image cropper added a overlay to crop the image but facing issue while cropping the image getting some error message in console when called crop function.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Image Cropper</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.0.0-beta3/css/all.min.css" />
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      height: 95vh;
      background-color: #222;
      color: #fff;
    }

    canvas {
      object-fit: contain;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 90vh;
      cursor: crosshair;
      display: block;
      background-color: #222;
      margin-top: 3vh;
    }

    .button-container {
      position: relative;
      margin-top: 10px;
    }

    .left-buttons {
      float: left;
      margin-left: 10px;
    }

    .right-buttons {
      float: right;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }

    .image-container {
      display: flex;
      justify-content: center;
      align-items: center;
      background-color: #222;
      position: relative;
    }

    .bottom-buttons {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      left: 10px;
      margin-bottom: 8px;
    }

    select {
      margin: 0 10px;
      background-color: #444;
      color: #fff;
    }

    /* Modal styles */
    .modal {
      display: none;
      position: fixed;
      z-index: 1;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      overflow: auto;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    }

    .modal-content {
      background-color: #333;
      margin: 0 auto;
      padding: 20px;
      border: 1px solid #888;
      width: 80%;
      max-width: 700px;
      position: relative;
      border-radius: 8px;
      color: #fff;
    }

    .close {
      position: absolute;
      top: 10px;
      right: 10px;
      color: #aaa;
      font-size: 28px;
      font-weight: bold;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .close:hover,
    .close:focus {
      color: #fff;
      text-decoration: none;
    }

    .modal-content img {
      max-width: 100%;
      height: auto;
      display: block;
      margin: auto;
    }

    .zoom-buttons {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 10px;
      right: 10px;
    }

    .zoom-buttons button {
      margin-left: 5px;
      background-color: #fff;
      color: black;
      border: none;
      padding: 5px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }

    .zoom-buttons button:hover {
      background-color: #666;
    }

    #overlay {
      position: absolute;
      width: 200px;
      height: 200px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
      border: 2px solid yellow;
      cursor: move;
    }

    #overlay div {
      position: absolute;
      width: 10px;
      height: 10px;
      background-color: white;
    }

    #overlay div.top-left {
      top: -5px;
      left: -5px;
      cursor: nwse-resize;
    }

    #overlay div.top-right {
      top: -5px;
      right: -5px;
      cursor: nesw-resize;
    }

    #overlay div.bottom-left {
      bottom: -5px;
      left: -5px;
      cursor: nesw-resize;
    }

    #overlay div.bottom-right {
      bottom: -5px;
      right: -5px;
      cursor: nwse-resize;
    }


    /* Crosshair style */
    #crosshair {
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      width: 0;
      height: 0;
      border-left: 1px solid white;
      border-right: 1px solid white;
      border-top: 1px solid white;
      border-bottom: 1px solid white;
      pointer-events: none;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="button-container">
    <div class="left-buttons">
      <img id="brookImage" src="rope41.png" style="display: none;" onload="loadImage()">
      <select id="shapeSelect" onchange="selectShape()">
        <option value="rectangle" selected>Rectangle</option>
        <option value="circle">Circle</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div class="right-buttons">
      <button onclick="cropImage()"><i class="fas fa-check"></i></button>
      <button onclick="resetImage()"><i class="fas fa-x"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <div id="overlay">
      <div id="crosshair"></div>
      <div class="top-left"></div>
      <div class="top-right"></div>
      <div class="bottom-left"></div>
      <div class="bottom-right"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="bottom-buttons">
    <button onclick="rotateLeft()"><i class="fas fa-rotate-left"></i></button>
    <button onclick="rotateRight()"><i class="fas fa-rotate-right"></i></button>
  </div>

  <div class="zoom-buttons bottom-right">
    <button onclick="zoomIn()"><i class="fas fa-search-plus"></i></button>
    <button onclick="zoomOut()"><i class="fas fa-search-minus"></i></button>
  </div>

  <!-- The Modal -->
  <div id="myModal" class="modal">
    <!-- Modal content -->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
      <img id="croppedImagePreview" src="" alt="Cropped Image" />
    </div>
  </div>

  <script>
    let canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    let ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    let imageObj = null;
    let startX, startY, endX, endY;
    let isDragging = false;
    let selectedShape = "rectangle";
    let shapes = [];
    let croppedCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
    let croppedCtx = croppedCanvas.getContext("2d");
    let scale = 1; // Initial scale
    let overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
    let offsetX, offsetY;
    let resizingCorner = null;

    function loadImage() {
      let imageElement = document.getElementById("brookImage");
      imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function () {
        canvas.width = imageObj.width;
        canvas.height = imageObj.height;
        ctx.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = imageElement.src;
    }

    function selectShape() {
      selectedShape = document.getElementById("shapeSelect").value;
    }

    function cropImage() {
      let shape = {
        type: selectedShape,
        startX: parseInt(overlay.style.left),
        startY: parseInt(overlay.style.top),
        endX: parseInt(overlay.style.left) + parseInt(overlay.style.width),
        endY: parseInt(overlay.style.top) + parseInt(overlay.style.height),
      };
      shapes.push(shape);

      let width = parseInt(overlay.style.width);
      let height = parseInt(overlay.style.height);

      let cropX = parseInt(overlay.style.left);
      let cropY = parseInt(overlay.style.top);

      // Use overlay position and size for cropping
      let tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
      let tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

      tempCanvas.width = width;
      tempCanvas.height = height;

      if (shape.type === "rectangle") {
        tempCtx.drawImage(
          canvas,
          cropX, cropY,
          width, height,
          0, 0,
          width, height
        );
      } else if (shape.type === "circle") {
        // Circle cropping remains the same
      }

      // Clear the canvas and draw the cropped image
      croppedCtx.clearRect(0, 0, croppedCanvas.width, croppedCanvas.height);
      croppedCanvas.width = width;
      croppedCanvas.height = height;
      croppedCtx.drawImage(tempCanvas, 0, 0);

      // Display the cropped image
      document.getElementById("croppedImagePreview").src = croppedCanvas.toDataURL();
      document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "block";

      console.log(croppedCanvas.toDataURL());
    }

    function updateOverlayPosition() {
      let overlayWidth = Math.abs(endX - startX);
      let overlayHeight = Math.abs(endY - startY);
      let overlayX = Math.min(startX, endX);
      let overlayY = Math.min(startY, endY);

      overlay.style.width = overlayWidth + "px";
      overlay.style.height = overlayHeight + "px";
      overlay.style.left = overlayX + "px";
      overlay.style.top = overlayY + "px";

      // Update crosshair position
      let crosshair = document.getElementById("crosshair");
      crosshair.style.left = overlayWidth / 2 + "px";
      crosshair.style.top = overlayHeight / 2 + "px";
    }

    function resetImage() {
      shapes = [];
      croppedCtx.clearRect(0, 0, croppedCanvas.width, croppedCanvas.height);
    }

    function closeModal() {
      document.getElementById("myModal").style.display = "none";
    }

    let rotation = 0;
    function rotateLeft() {
      rotation -= Math.PI / 2;
      drawRotatedImage(rotation);
    }

    function rotateRight() {
      rotation += Math.PI / 2;
      drawRotatedImage(rotation);
    }

    function drawRotatedImage(rotation) {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.rotate(rotation);
      ctx.drawImage(
        imageObj,
        -canvas.width / 2,
        -canvas.height / 2,
        canvas.width,
        canvas.height
      );
      ctx.restore();
    }

    overlay.addEventListener('mousedown', function (event) {
      isDragging = true;
      let rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
      offsetX = event.clientX - rect.left - overlay.offsetLeft;
      offsetY = event.clientY - rect.top - overlay.offsetTop;

      console.log("OffsetX:", offsetX);
      console.log("OffsetY:", offsetY);

      document.addEventListener('mousemove', dragOverlay);

      function dragOverlay(event) {
        let mouseX = event.clientX - rect.left;
        let mouseY = event.clientY - rect.top;

        // Calculate the new position for the overlay
        let newLeft = mouseX - offsetX;
        let newTop = mouseY - offsetY;

        // Ensure the overlay stays within the bounds of the canvas
        newLeft = Math.min(Math.max(0, newLeft), rect.width - overlay.offsetWidth);
        newTop = Math.min(Math.max(0, newTop), rect.height - overlay.offsetHeight);

        overlay.style.left = newLeft + 'px';
        overlay.style.top = newTop + 'px';
      }

      document.addEventListener('mouseup', function () {
        isDragging = false;
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', dragOverlay);
      });
    });


    function updateOverlayPosition() {
      let overlay = document.getElementById("overlay");
      let overlayWidth = Math.abs(startX - endX);
      let overlayHeight = Math.abs(startY - endY);
      let overlayX = Math.min(startX, endX);
      let overlayY = Math.min(startY, endY);

      overlay.style.width = overlayWidth + "px";
      overlay.style.height = overlayHeight + "px";
      overlay.style.left = overlayX + "px";
      overlay.style.top = overlayY + "px";

      // Update crosshair position
      let crosshair = document.getElementById("crosshair");
      crosshair.style.left = overlayWidth / 2 + "px";
      crosshair.style.top = overlayHeight / 2 + "px";
    }

    function zoomIn() {
      scale += 0.1;
      drawZoomedImage();
    }

    function zoomOut() {
      scale -= 0.1;
      drawZoomedImage();
    }

    function drawZoomedImage() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.save();
      ctx.translate(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2);
      ctx.scale(scale, scale);
      ctx.drawImage(imageObj, -canvas.width / 2, -canvas.height / 2, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.restore();
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>


let width = parseInt(overlay.style.width); - you can only read style properties this way, if they were set via inline style, or JS - which does not appear to be the case here. Use overlay.offsetWidth (and offsetHeight for the other one) instead.

The error message is gone for now but the crop function still not working as expected getting empty/transparent image in cropped base64 URL.
